# Yii 1.1 route issue if install is in folder

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a controller to display some data and my yii install is in a folder named api.

If i navigate to localhost/api/mycontroller I get a 404 error.

But if I put my yii install in my root folder and navigate to localhost/mycontroller it works.

Any tips what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it seems that you are very new to yii i recommend  you to read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)

Comment: [Not related to QA] Any specific reason why you are not using Yii version 2 or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add index.php on the path and see it works or not.

e.g localhost/index.php/api/mycontroller

If it works, you can hide 'index.php' follow the guide below.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/